# PHP regular expression any kind of letter from any language

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create my own routing in php using regex,
my example returns true when the name is in latain, but when the name is in arabic returns false

```
preg_match('#^(en/users/(?<name>[\p{L}\p{Nd}\_\-\+]+))$#', 'en/users/علي+عثمان')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match arabic script you have to use `\p{Arabic}` instead of `\p{L}`, and also set the pattern modifier `u` to enable UTF-8 support.

Like so:

```
preg_match('#^(en/users/([\p{L}\p{Ll}\p{Arabic}\p{Nd}\_\-\+]+))$#u', 'en/users/علي+عثمان')
```

Working example: https://ideone.com/Zwrnpg